# message forwards settings in mail

Tags: messaging, forward, qmail

Is there a way in qmail to set forward messages. Like for instance a support person might leave the company and if a client sends a mail to his id then a mail should be send asking him to use another mail id i.e the id of the person to whom work has been transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you are asking for two different things.

1) Forwarding a mail (sending the incoming mail automatically to another user)

I consider you are using the mbox-format with qmail and you are configuring your email-adresses with the .qmail-:- files

Open the .qmail-File of the emailadress oyu want to forward. There you will find the name of the current receipient (mailbox).

Adding the following line will send all incomming messages to another email-adress in copy:

```
&some-other@email.com
```

By removing the existing lines, the message will be forwared only to the newly added email-adress.

2) Autoresponder (Replying to the sender with an email, asking him to use another email-adress)

An autoresponder for qmail ist the qmail-autoresponder, that can be found here: http://untroubled.org/qmail-autoresponder/

After installing the qmail-autoresponder, you have to add the following line to the .qmail-file:

```
|qmail-autoresponder /path/to/autorespond-directory-of-email-adress
```

You can use both - fowarding and autoresponding in the same .qmail-file. Just write all lines under each other.